# Hash sign in Angular Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have problem with # sign in angular routing.
I have navigation links that shoud be without leading slash sign, like that:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#services"> УСЛУГИ</a></li>
```

Otherwise scrollspy is not working (if I'm using `<a href="#/services">`).
But now here is problem with Angular routing that configured this way:

```
config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
            .when('/objects', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/objects.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
            .when('/object/:Id', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/object.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
```

How should I change routing (or scrollspy) configuration to be able using these navigation links for both purposes - scrollspy and angular routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get rid of the `#` sign in route by using `$locationProvider` module

```
config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
            controller: 'smu72Controller'
        })
        .when('/objects', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/objects.html',
            controller: 'smu72Controller'
        })
        .when('/object/:Id', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/object.html',
            controller: 'smu72Controller'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });

        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: Ok, yes, it's working. But you know what, when I'm on this route /object/:Id', navigation just not working, user cannot come back to home page. How this could be fixed?

Comment: you might want to take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview and rewrite your config